# C - Linked list program giving the error "Return value ignored: 'scanf'". Also please point out if you find any other mistakes

Tags: c, data-structures, dynamic, linked-list

I am trying to write a code to implement a linked list. The program inserts a value taken from the user into a linked list until the user exits execution. The value can be inserted into the head, tail or any custom position entered by the user.

Upon compiling the program gives the error "Return value ignored: 'scanf'" on every scanf. It also gave an error saying scanf is unsafe, use scanf_s instead. I resolved that by adding '_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS' to preprocessor definitions. Also please point out if you find any other mistakes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} node;

typedef enum position { First = 1, Custom, Last} position;
typedef enum process {Exit, Run} process;

node* insertFirst(node* ptrHead, int val)
{
    node* temp = NULL;
    node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    
    if (newNode == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        if (ptrHead == NULL)
        {
            newNode->data = val;
            newNode->next = NULL;
            ptrHead = newNode;
        }
        else 
        {
            temp = ptrHead;
            newNode->data = val;
            newNode->next = temp;
            ptrHead = newNode;
        }
    }
    return ptrHead;
}

node* insertPos(node* ptrHead, int val, int loc)
{
    node* temp = ptrHead;
    node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    
    if (newNode == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < loc; i++)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    newNode->data = val;
    newNode->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = newNode;

    return ptrHead;
}


node* insertLast(node* ptrHead, int val)
{
    node* temp = ptrHead;
    node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    if (newNode == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    newNode->data = val;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = newNode;

    return ptrHead;
}

void printList(node* ptrHead)
{
    node* temp = ptrHead;

    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int countNodes(node* ptrHead)
{
    node* temp = ptrHead;
    int i = 0;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    node* ptrHead = NULL;
    position location;
    int num = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    process state = Run;

    while (state == Run)
    {
        printf(" Welcome to my Linked List program. \n");
        if (ptrHead == NULL)
        {
            printf("Enter first element of the list \n");
            scanf("%d", &num);
            ptrHead = insertFirst(ptrHead, num);
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" Enter number to choose location: \n 1 -> First\n 2-> Custom\n 3-> Last\n");
            scanf("%d", &pos);
            if (pos == Custom)
            {
                printf("Please enter the number and the placement\n");
                scanf("%d", &num);
                scanf("%d", &location);
                if (location > countNodes(ptrHead))
                {
                    printf("Enter position less than %d\n", countNodes(ptrHead));
                }
                else
                {
                    ptrHead = insertPos(ptrHead, num, location);
                }

            }
            else if (pos == First)
            {
                printf("Please enter the number\n");
                scanf("%d", &num);
                ptrHead = insertFirst(ptrHead, num);
            }
            else if (pos == Last)
            {
                printf("Please enter the number\n");
                scanf("%d", &num);
                ptrHead = insertLast(ptrHead, num);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Wrong position entry\n");
            }
        }
        printList(ptrHead);

        printf("Enter '1' to insert another value and '0' to quit execution\n");
        scanf("%d", &state);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to check the return value to see if it succeeded or not before you can use values it tries to read.

Comment: Well, your compiler is trying to warn you in its wisdom. Pay attention, read about why you shouldn't use `scanf` for user inputs, believe me you won't have any shortage of posts about that on SO.